# Given a form with multiple submit buttons, can I control them individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with two submit buttons: one updates the quantity of items in the cart, the other lets the user proceed to checkout. If there is no item in the cart that is a "shipping" item, then I would like the user not to be able to checkout. I would still like the user to be able to update the quantity.

Originally I used this javascript:

```
  $('#cartform').submit(function (e) {
    console.log(e)

    if ($('.item.shipping').length > 0) {
      // there are Shipping items in the cart, so proceed
      console.log("OK to checkout")
    } else {
      // there are no Shipping items so display help
      console.log("NO")
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#shipping-calculator-info p').text("Please select shipping destination.")    
    }
  });
```

I soon realized that this also disabled the update quantity button.

My initial thought was to catch the `click` event from just the button I want to deal with, and `preventDefault` on it. This doesn't seem to prevent the submit from happening though. Next I thought that perhaps `e`, the event, might have a field specifying the event's origin -- then I would be able to add a condition to the above `submit` code. I was not able to find such a field though (and I read hints that this information does not exist).

How can I prevent the default action of just one of a number of submit buttons on the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you've done now, you're referencing the form, and not the button. No problem, you just need to use jQuery's awesome selectors to find the submit buttons. Here's a working example:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="formDataHandler.php">
<input name='text1' type='text' value='text input'><br />
<input id='subBtn1' type='submit' value='submit 1'><br />
<input id='subBtn2' type='submit' value='submit 2'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form1").find('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
alert($(e.target).val());
    if ($(e.target).val() == 'submit 1') { 
    e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: e.target seems to give me the DOM element that was being submitted, which is the form. Can you give me an example of how you would use e.target to determine which submit button was clicked to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attach to the form's submit event, why not attach to the actual button's click event?

That way you can provide the appropriate code for each button.  You can submit the form using JavaScript in the checkout button's handler, and just update the DOM from your Update button.

Comment: I actually don't have access to the form itself, so the buttons will always submit the form. I wrote a click handler to preventDefault, but that didn't seem to prevent the form from being submitted. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Ziggy: If you can write a click handler for a button, you can always prevent it from submitting the form.  Just `return false;` from the button handler.

Comment: @EricJ. The problem is that he doesn't know how to reference the element in the form. He was referencing the form id, not the button ids, I couldn't understand what the problem was until I realized that :P. I just posted a solution using jQuery selectors to get to the button elements.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `return false;`.

```
$('#cartform').submit(function (e) {
    console.log(e)

    if ($('.item.shipping').length > 0) {
      // there are Shipping items in the cart, so proceed
      console.log("OK to checkout")
    } else {
      // there are no Shipping items so display help
      console.log("NO")
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#shipping-calculator-info p').text("Please select shipping destination.")    
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Given a form with multiple submit buttons, can I control them individually? 

For example, if there are two submit buttons, A and B, can I write logic in a submit handler to behave a certain way if A submitted the form and another way if B submitted the form?

Comment: I'd go with Eric J's suggestion if you'd like to control the onsubmit events for discrete buttons.

Comment: @Ziggy You can absolutely, I found out what you problem was and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround that you could use is to "convert" the submit buttons to simple buttons, then bind your code to the click events, and from within the click events, when appropriate you could use:

```
$('#cartform').submit();
```

to manually submit the form.

Comment: This is a good option, but I actually don't have access to the form. I can't touch the form itself, I just know how many buttons it has.

Comment: Ok, then, bind them to the click events and then use preventDefault() to stop the submission when not desired. I tested that in a simple demo form but only on Chrome and it worked...

Comment: Just like the post from @TheWeirdNerd below. If you have trouble selecting the buttons if they are do not have any special ids or classes, then you can use .first() and .last() or the :first and :last